# iTerm2 + oh-my-bash: iTerm2 shell-integration not working

Tags: bash, shell, iterm2

I cannot get iTerm2's shell integration work with oh-my-bash. I already tried the suggestions in the existing posts but without luck. My configuration looks as follow:

- iTerm2 profile

  - **General** -> **Command** -> **Custom Shell**: /usr/local/bin/bash
  - **Send text at start**: source ~/.bashrc  (*required to activate oh-my-bash*)
- My login shell (according to `chsh`): /usr/local/bin/bash

I have installed the iTerm2 Shell integration using the integrated installer.

Removing the **Send text at start** command makes the Shell integration work, however, also disabled oh-my-bash. I tested it, for example, using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> shortcut which allows jumping between marks.

### Approaches

I tried playing around with

- iTerm2 profile: Login Shell / Custom Command
- Sourcing `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` manually

However, I could not accomplish to have at the same time oh-my-bash enabled, the iTerm2 Shell integration working, and the tools that are initialized in ~/.bash_profile (e.g., `brew` and `itermocil`) working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by using the following configuration:

- iTerm2 profile

  - **General** -> **Command** -> **Custom Shell**: `/usr/local/bin/bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc`
  - **Send text at start**: `source ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash; osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'`

The command `source ~/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash` activates the shell integration. The snippet `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "k" using command down'` clears the buffer by invoking the <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> keystroke – note that `clear` could also be used instead but this only moves the terminal's visible content and enlarging the window possibly shows the content.